# Allow Docker strategy in Openshift 3

Tags: ubuntu, docker, openshift, dockerfile, openshift-origin

I'm trying to understand the new OpenShift system and now we have push images to it. I know a little about Docker and I wanted to use it. I read in some places that we can chose Docker as a strategy.

So basically I created an image based on `httpd` and a basic html file and tried to push it with the following command from the project folder:

```
oc new-app . --strategy=docker
```

I get this message on console:

> error: buildconfigs.build.openshift.io "openshift" is forbidden: build strategy Docker is not allowed

What do I have to do to allow it? I don't see a good explanation anywhere...

Comment: You can just build your image locally and push it to OpenShifts Image Registry. OpenShift rebuilds and deploys your app as soon as the new image version finished uploading. Here is a nice tutorial for that strategy: https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-docker-registry/

Comment: I followed the blog indicated by @Rotareti above and it worked, all you need to do is:
1) tag the image using Openshift repository name and your project name
`docker tag <image_id> <repo>/<project>/<app_name>`
2) push the image using the tag just created
`docker push <image_tag>`
3) create the app
`oc new-app <app_name> --name=<svc_name>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using OpenShift Online, it is not possible to enable the `docker` build type. For OpenShift Online your options are to build your image locally and then push it up to an external image registry such as Docker Hub, or login to the internal OpenShift registry and push your image directly in to it. The image can then be used in a deployment.

If you have set up your own OpenShift cluster, my understanding is that `docker` build type should be enabled by default. You can find more details at:

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/admin_guide/securing_builds.html

If you are after a way to deploy a site using a `httpd` web server, there is a S2I builder image available that can do that. See:

- https://github.com/sclorg/httpd-container

Comment: Im using that Openshift 3. I use the web console. Does that mean it is the Open Shift Online?

Comment: If you are going to https://manage.openshift.com/ to login, that is OpenShift Online.

Comment: Does OpenShift Online allow other build strategies (for images), or does it strictly insist on images being built outside?

Comment: OpenShift Online provides the ``source`` build strategy (S2I). Neither ``docker`` or ``custom`` build strategies are enabled. So you can build images in OpenShift Online, but only using the ``source`` build strategy.

Comment: I have been using Openshift for quite some time. Unfortunately I use Docker build type. I need to move to the cloud so I tried Amazon EKS. That was going to be a lot of work to convert my templates so I spun up Openshift Online. Come to find out they limit what I can do and I'll have to convert my templates anyway. Well, back to Amazon EKS. If I have to convert my templates anyway, I might as well take the time to convert to the industry standard.

Answer (score 0):

You could always setup Minishift locally to build your images using the Docker build strategy if you wanted to gain experience with this strategy.

https://docs.openshift.org/latest/minishift/getting-started/installing.html